# How can I iterate python list ( appended Lists) in Java Script

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, list

I have a value which is basically set of appended python lists .
How can I iterate them in JS .

My value looks like :

```
 value =  [['A', ' PARIKH', "None", "None"], 
           ['B', 'MANISH ', "None", "None"], 
           ['C', 'SHIV ', "None", "None"], 
           ['D', ' GAUR', "None", "None"]]
```

Comment: How is this python list represented in your JavaScript program? Putting that code into JS will throw an error (due to the `None`)

Comment: Why do you want to loop through a `python` list in `javascript`? I guess you have a somehow serialized structure (`string`, `JSON`, ...)  to communicate and do not really want to access th values as known to the python interpreter? 
In this case, just use a JS loop...

Comment: Assume none as "None" @NickParsons

Comment: Its just that I have a value in this format . Is there any way to iterate each record .?@Cpt.Hook

Comment: @SuryaSingh I don't really see what python has to do with this question then. You have a javascript array, which you can loop over using for loops, in a similar way that you can with python.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function in Javascript:

```
let a = [["a","c"],["b","d"]]
a.map(x => x[1])
```

output:

```
Array [ "c", "d" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just loop through the array and then loop through every array after that

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {  }
     for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++)
          console.log(arr[i][j]);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Code:-**

```
var myStringArray = [['A', 'PARIKH', "None", "None"], 
           ['B', 'MANISH ', "None", "None"], 
           ['C', 'SHIV ', "None", "None"], 
           ['D', ' GAUR', "None", "None"]] 
// Accessing by list by list
for (var i = 0; i < myStringArray.length; i++) {
    console.log(myStringArray[i]);  
}

// Accessing by element by element in the list
for (var i = 0; i < myStringArray.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<myStringArray[i].length; j++){
    console.log(myStringArray[i][j]);
    }
}
```

**Output:-**

```
[ 'A', 'PARIKH', 'None', 'None' ]
[ 'B', 'MANISH ', 'None', 'None' ]
[ 'C', 'SHIV ', 'None', 'None' ]
[ 'D', ' GAUR', 'None', 'None' ]
A
PARIKH
None
None
B
MANISH 
None
None
C
SHIV 
None
None
D
GAUR
None
None
```